# Comparing two sets of data from same table and column without calling the table twice in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make my query more efficient because it is still heavy and in the future it will get allot worst.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(fb_diff.shares) shares
FROM (
    SELECT (SUM(fb.shares) - SUM(fbs.shares)) shares
    FROM (
        SELECT post_id, shares
        FROM wp_facebook_total_stats
        WHERE date = '2014-08-01 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY post_id
    ) fbs
    LEFT JOIN wp_facebook_total_stats fb ON fb.post_id = fbs.post_id
    WHERE fb.date = '2014-09-28'
) fb_diff
```

It works... I get the data... But is there a way to the same without getting the same table twice?

Because when I do EXPLAIN, I get this:

```
2    DERIVED     fb                        ALL      post_id    NULL       NULL   NULL   588849    Using where
3    DERIVED     wp_facebook_total_stats   index    post_id    post_id    8      NULL   588849    Using where
```

Comment: Can you show your table structure, sample data and an explanation of what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Include `fd.date` in your index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the difference between post shares based on different dates or lapsed time and don't want to join recursively to the same table, I can see at least a couple of options:

1. Create a view that does this ahead of time and can be cached then query the view.
2. Pull the data into an array within your code by changing your select statement to group on date and post_id, then doing the math within your code to show shares differences.
3. Modify your schema to better meet your needs, if possible. For example add a column(s) to wp_facebook_total_stats which shows difference between shares versus previous day, previous week, previous month, etc. Whatever you will need to get the job done.

Each option has its benefits and drawbacks, consider them carefully.

Hope this helps, good luck.